# Qt: How to set border for a subtext in a qtextEdit

Tags: qt, pyqt

I want to set border for a subtext in QTextEdit. I used this:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTextEdit,QApplication
import sys
app =QApplication(sys.argv)
t=QTextEdit()
t.setHtml('<p>This is a <span style="border: 2px solid #FF0000">test</span> !</p>')
t.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

but it does not work and border doesn't set.
Also, I couldn't find any property for `QtextEsit.setCurrentCharFormat` to set border color.
How can I do it in pyQt 5.5.1?

Comment: [Supported HTML Subset](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html)

Comment: I saw this link, but it didn't help me.

Comment: It does help you, because it makes it clear that borders are only supported for table elements. And there are many other standard HTML attributes and CSS properties that are **not** supported by Qt, so you need to read that linked documentation to understand what is possible.

Comment: So,  what can I do to set border for subtext in QtextEdit?